# Proof by Induction that Knapsack recurrence returns optimum solution

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, induction

I have to show by induction that

if w < w_i then Opt(i,w) = Opt(i-1,w)
, else Opt(i,w) = max{ Opt(i-1,w), Opt( i-1, w - w_i) + w_i) }

produces the optimal solution for the Knapsack Problem (Dynamic Programming approach)

I know how mathematical induction works, but I'm stuck on how to do it with this exercise.
Especially the inductive step.
As base case, I imagine, I only got one element and as long as the weight of this element is smaller or equal the capacity of my knapsack, I'll take it. 
Otherwise I leave it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To prove the correctness of this algorithm you can follow the following three steps

1. Prove that the algorithm produces a viable list:

Because the algorithm describes that we will make the largest choice available and we will always make a choice, we have a viable list

2. Prove that the algorithm has greedy choice property:

In this case we want to prove that the first choice of our algorithm could be part of the optimal solution.

3. Prove that the algorithm has optimal substructure: We can do so by hypothetically forming two list:

U(the optimal list) and P(the list chosen by our algorithm). We can assume that the two list must be different at some point. Let the point of difference be Uj and Pj (that is after index j, P would contain different object from U, U ends at index j). Because in P is selected by only picking the largest element, with the same amount of element up to j as U does, Pj+1 will overflow the knapsack or we will be making the optimal solution U better which is not possible. Therefore, this problem has optimal substructure.

This way we can prove that the algorithm is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A problem has "optimal substructure" if it can be broken down into subproblems and you can find the optimal solutions to subproblems using recursion. Your problem has optimal substructure (As does any DP solvable problem!). Proof that your program will indeed result in the optimal solution, using induction, can be found [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/proof-of-0-1-knapsack-optimal-substructure).